# Combine Multiple Partitions

Tags: partitioning

I have a freshly installed ubuntu 20.04 server in vbox.  The file system disk has LVM disk partitions.

How can I combine the 3 partitions below into 1 partition under `/dev/sda1`?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F33494A4-78A9-438D-867A-921E959880ED

Device       Start       End   Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048      4095      2048   1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096   4198399   4194304   2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  4198400 209713151 205514752  98G Linux filesystem
```

Re-stating the goal is... I need to add the content of `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3` into `/dev/sda1`

Comment: Don't touch `/dev/sda1` it is necessary to boot from a gpy partition with a legacy BIOS. It is a bad idea that you are planning.

Comment: @Pilot6 I agree with you... I always thought it was impossible to combine them...because boot has to be outside of the LVM... but I was asked to do exactly what is written above...

Comment: @nightwatch Don't always do what you're asked. And who's asking? You'll totally break the system.

Comment: @heynnema  Don't worry, I don't... that is why I posted here before attempting the impossible.  My new ECS webhost provider made the request.  In order to upload my custom Ubuntu server VDI image into their system I was instructed to combine the above partitions... I am starting to think tech support is a few skittles shy of a full pack...

Comment: Putting `/boot` into LVM is possible, towards the bottom of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019 has instructions of putting `/boot` into LVM but it has to be LUKS1 for it to work.  As far as the combining goes, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67993/111521 has steps that look like they work.  I know it says CentOS, but the commands look identical to that of what Ubuntu would use.  I guess you could always setup a VirtualBox VM the same way and test out the combining and see if it all works.

Comment: @Terrance thanks for the feedback, but the encryption would interrupt their services... and now this is a nil question... I got the VDI to work with the 3 partitions above... I figured the tech agent is nuts and I should just go with what I know...